# Generic repository accessor in a unit of work

Tags: c#, design-patterns, dependency-injection, repository

I'm giving the repository + UoW patterns my first shot on the server side, so bear with me. Also, it's worth mentioning that I haven't used an IoC container on the server side before either, so I'll post its setup too. I'm using [simple injector](https://simpleinjector.org/index.html) at the moment.

All kinds of feedback is appreciated, especially for `UnitOfWork.GetRepository<T>()` a bit below, which I'm not very satisfied with.

```
var container = new Container();

container.Options.DefaultScopedLifestyle = new AsyncScopedLifestyle();

container.Register(typeof(IUnitOfWork), typeof(UnitOfWork), Lifestyle.Scoped);

container.RegisterWebApiControllers(GlobalConfiguration.Configuration);

container.Verify();

GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.DependencyResolver = 
                                     new SimpleInjectorWebApiDependencyResolver(container);
```

```
public interface IUnitOfWork
{
    DatabaseRepository<T> GetRepository<T>() where T : BaseEntity;
    Task CommitAsync();
}
```

```
public class UnitOfWork : IUnitOfWork, IDisposable
{
    private readonly Entities _context = new Entities();
    private readonly IDictionary<Type, object> _repositories = new Dictionary<Type, object>();

    public DatabaseRepository<T> GetRepository<T>() where T : BaseEntity
    {
        var type = typeof(T);

        if (!_repositories.ContainsKey(type))
        {
            var instance = (DatabaseRepository<T>)Activator.CreateInstance(typeof(DatabaseRepository<T>), _context);
            _repositories[type] = instance;
        }

        return _repositories[type] as DatabaseRepository<T>;
    }

    public async Task CommitAsync()
    {
        try
        {
            await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
        }
        catch (DbEntityValidationException e)
        {
            // todo: handle validation errors...
            throw;
        }
    }

    private bool _disposed;

    protected virtual void Dispose(bool disposing)
    {
        if (!_disposed)
        {
            if (disposing)
            {
                _context.Dispose();
            }
        }
        _disposed = true;
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        Dispose(true);
        GC.SuppressFinalize(this);
    }
}
```